# Run module for specific environment only in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have multiple nested modules and want to exclude a module from running in one environment. I read about count in modules that I think may work but it is only supported from v0.13.

module/vm/main.tf

```
#Create VM
....
....
....
```

module/web/main.tf

```
module "nginx_node" {
  source = "../vm"
  vm_name = "nginx"
  cpu = var.cpu
  disk_size = var.disk_size
  dc = var.dc
}

module "mysql_node" {
  source = "../vm"
  vm_name = "mysql"
  cpu = var.cpu
  disk_size = var.disk_size
  dc = var.dc
}
```

dev/main.tf

```
module "nodes" {
  source = "../web"
  disk_size = 20
  cpu = 2
  dc = var.dc
}
....
....
```

prod/main.tf

```
module "nodes" {
  source = "../web"
  disk_size = 40
  cpu = 4
  dc = var.dc
}
....
....
```

How can I omit module "nginx_node" from running in my dev environment (dev/main.tf) and only in prod environment?

Comment: If you don't use TF 0.13 or newer, then you can't do that, unless you fully separate your scripts.

Comment: even prior to TF 0.13 you can pass an `enabled` as a variable to the module and have the resources inside that module add that to their existing logic or add a new count to those that don't have it